# Loading large sets in EF and saving changes

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a problem with Entity Framework I hope someone might want to help with :)

**The feature I'm trying to implement**: My application should be able to take an XML-dump from a third party application, look at the data and compare with what's in the applications database and update any entities depending on non-trivial criteria, which is based on both the XML-version and the DB-version of an entity.

**Approach**: Load all data into memory (EF for DB) and do all comparison in memory and write updates back to DB.

**Background for approach** (optional reading): The customer I'm working for has faced this type of problem a few times earlier, and has never been quite happy with the solutions they have found earlier. They have concluded with that this is the best approach. So I'm not looking for alternative solutions at this point, rather to either find out how to do it this was or be confident it can't be done in a reasonable amount of time.

**My problem**: Loading the XML into memory was no problem, loading from the DB much more so. The heart of the problem is that the data is stored into 8 tables with connections and tha main table has nearly 500 000 rows. The result is a complicated query which returns a lot of data. I've tried several approaches:

**1)** Just loading it all in one big request from the SQL Server. Seems to work find for a while, while reading, until it uses about 1.6 GB of RAM, when I get a OutOfMemoryException - even if there is nearly 10 GB of free RAM. The Exception comes from within EF. At the time of the exception, about half the records had been read.

**2)** Use Skip/Take to read it piece by piece. Requires OrderBy, so I order by the primary key of the primary table (int, sequential but not autoincrement). This makes the query a lot more complicated, with 15+ ORDER BY statements at the end, about 5 of which are to columns that actually are copies of the primary key I'm sorting by. Don't know why there are so many copies, but they're there... The query times out - of course.

**3)** Select all primary keys from the main table, sorted. Then take the first 1000 and create a limit pair containing the smallest and the biggest of these 1000. Repeat for all groups of 1000 until done. Now call the query several times, checking the primary key between the two numbers in each of the pairs, to load the set 1000 at a time. This turned out to be extremely slow - taking 45 sec per group of 1000, which is far from acceptable.

Option **1** seems to be closest to working, but there seems to be a memory limitation internally of EF. Might it be possible to adjust this somehow?

I'm at the point where I'm thinking of abandoning EF for this task (even if it's being used throughout the application elsewhere), but thought I'd give you the problem to chew on first ;-)

Comment: Is the application compiled as 32bit app? You would have a natural limitation of 2 GB process memory then which is normally not completely usable due to possible memory fragmentations. With 64bit app and OS you would have much more memory available in process space, still minus possible fragmentations, but probably enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default platform target for most Visual Studio project templates is x86. You will need to change your project to target x64 or Any CPU to be able to use more than 2GB of memory. To do this, go to your project's properties, Build tab, select Any CPU under Platform target.

Loading 500,000 rows at once still sounds like a bad idea to me though, and you still may run into other problems with approach #1.

Comment: Most of the time Stack Overflow is a great place to ask a question and get an informative answer from which to learn - other times it is a place to realize what an idiot you are when you read the obvious answer... Thanks for making me feel like an idiot - it saved me a lot of time ;-)